# Suitable way of using JPQL BETWEEN clause with dates

Tags: date, jpa, jpql

Is there any good way to trunc date in JPQL? For instance, I have table with a column in which I write current date (new Date()) and then I need to search through this column using the BETWEEN operator. The problem here is that I need to config date params to beginning and the ending of the day, such as: 2016-05-02 00:00:00 and 2016-05-02-23:59:59. I do have utility methods to do this, but I was wondering if is there any other good alternative.

Comment: You need to have utility methods. JPA does not have any facility to do this.

Comment: What do you usually do?

Comment: Exactly what you did. Before pass the date parameters for the jpql query, we call a method for each parameter, to set the start date in 00:00 and set the end date in 23:59.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, `DATE_TRUNC` is not a function defined in `JPQL` and as a result, none of the JPA implementations - such as Hibernate - support this function.

`DATE_TRUNC` can however be registered as a custom function in various JPA implementations.

For example, for Hibernate:

```java
public class DateTruncMetadataBuilderInitializer
        implements MetadataBuilderInitializer {
    @Override
    public void contribute(MetadataBuilder metadataBuilder,
            StandardServiceRegistry serviceRegistry) {
        metadataBuilder.applySqlFunction("DATE_TRUNC",
            new SQLFunctionTemplate(DateType.INSTANCE,
                "DATE_TRUNC(?1, ?2)"));
    }
}
```

You would then need to register this class in a JAR resource file called `META-INF/services/org.hibernate.boot.spi.MetadataBuilderInitializer`.

After this change you can use `DATE_TRUNC` in your JPQL/HQL queries, like so:

```sql
SELECT a FROM Entity a 
    WHERE a.dateField BETWEEN DATE_TRUNC('day', :start) AND DATE_TRUNC('day', :end)
```